# Maven classpath construction

Tags: maven, compilation, zip

I have Nexus as my local repository server, and the administrator added db2 jdbc driver to it, which contains several jar files and one zip: db2java.zip.
The Nexus administrator added db2java.zip in this location:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2java</artifactId>
        <version>08.02.0000</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
```

When i put it into my project and run "mvn clean compile" it downloads db2java.zip to my local repo (.m2 dir) but doesn't add the dependency (db2java.zip) to the classpath when Maven tries to compile the project. So, i get build errors.

¿How do i do to make db2java.zip be included in the classpath?

I haven't had any problems with other zillions of JAR dependencies on my projects, so this behaviour is ocurring because the dependency is a ZIP file.
One solution would be to change the extension from zip to jar, but i prefer to stick with the original extension (ZIP) because that's how it is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the `db2 maven configuration` at the [OpenJPA SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openjpa/trunk/openjpa-persistence-jdbc/pom.xml) which mentions as the following: -

***Please note you may need to extract the zip file for collecting some jar files first.***

#### 1. Install the jdbc driver to your local repository (or the Repository Manager)

```bsh
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=${path to db2jcc.jar} \
                         -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 \
                         -DartifactId=jcc-driver \
                         -Dversion=9.5 \
                         -Dpackaging=jar

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=${path to db2jcc_license.jar} \
                         -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 \
                         -DartifactId=jcc-license \
                         -Dversion=9.5 \
                         -Dpackaging=jar
```

#### 2. Make the dependency to that jar files

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcc-driver</artifactId>
        <version>9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcc-license</artifactId>
        <version>9.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I hope this may help.